# C# How to access value of Selected property of SelectListItem in LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below LINQ statement and I would like to know how to view the values of the paramaters in the `string.Equals` operator at runtime. Can anyone tell me how to setup my code, perhaps using a `var`, in order to do that?

```
Items = from Item in GetList()
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Selected = string.Equals(Item.Value, formTypeSelected, StringComparison.IgnoreCase),
        Text = Item.Key,
        Value = Item.Value                               
    };
```

Comment: LINQ returns an `IEnumerable`. You have to enumerate `IEnumerable`s in order to access the elements contained within them.

Comment: LINQ is executed lazily. I.e., this statement is only preparing the query but not executing it. If you want to see how it is executed, you must enumerate it in a for-each, for example. Also, it might be easier to set a break point if you extract the Equals part into a helper method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the execution of query returning `IEnumerable` is deferred, so you won't get so much of it unless you ask for the data, for example when you convert it `ToList<T>`:

```
Items = (from Item in GetList()
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Selected = string.Equals(Item.Value, formTypeSelected, StringComparison.IgnoreCase),
        Text = Item.Key,
        Value = Item.Value                               
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want, but do you need the SelectListItem that is currently Selected? If yes:

```
var selectedItem = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Selected);
// selectedItem will be of type SelectListItem
```

You can use `First` if you're sure that there will always be a selected item on the list.